# LIBSVM - no probability estimates

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I'm using LIBSVM for matlab. When I use a regression SVM the probability estimates it outputs are an empty matrix, whereas this feature works fine when using classification. Is this a normal behavior, because in the LIBSVM readme it says:

```
-b probability_estimates: whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates,
   0 or 1 (default 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[~,~,P] = svmpredict(x,y,model,'-b 1');
```

The output `P` is the probability of `y` belongs to class `1` and `-1` respectively (`m*2` array), and it only makes sense for classification problem.

For regression problem, the [pairwise probability information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_error_probability) is included in your trained model with `model.ProbA`.

Comment: should be `-b` be always activated in case of classification problems (e.g., binary)? if this is not true, when should one activate it? does it impact on the output?